# select box posting to jquery ajax appends [] to the field name

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a select box on a page that does a post with jQuery using .ajax and it works great when the select box can only select one value, but when I change it to "multiple" it appends [] to the end of the field name. For example listID without multiple is fine, but with "multiple" as an attribute changes the name to listID[]. Any idea what's happening?

```
<select multiple size="5" name="frmRecipientList" id="listID">

$.ajax({
            url: '/app/components/MailingsReport.cfc',
            //POST method is used
            type: "POST",
            complete: function(){
                $("#loader").hide();
            },
            //pass the data 
            data: {
                method: "createEmailing",
                title: $('#title').val(),
                campaignID: $('#campaignID').val(),
                brandID: $('#brandID').val(),
                listID: $('#listID').val(),
                maxRecipients: $('#maxRecipients').val(),
                subject: $('#subject').val(),
                fromName: $('#viewFrom').val(),
                testToEmail: $('#testToEmail').val(),
                htmlCode:  $('#htmlCode').val()
                 },
            dataType: "html",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listID` is `<select multiple>`.  That means there can be multiple values.  The `[]` makes it an array, so on the server, it can read all the values.

Comment: But the actual name is listID[] = 51 (if I chose value 51) and if I chose multiple the .ajax post is listID[]=51 and listID[]=52. Why isn't it listID=51,52 ?

Comment: @user1431633: Because that's how query strings (and POST data) work.  It's POSTed as `listID[]=51&listID[]=52`, because that's how it works.  In your backend, that should be an array.  For example, in PHP: `print_r($_POST['listID'])` is `array(51, 52)`.

Comment: Here's a solution to it... http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/3/23/Using-jQuery-to-post-an-array-to-a-ColdFusion-Component

Comment: @user1431633: Sorry, I don't know ColdFusion.  I'm a PHP guy.

Comment: Basically I was trying to post a complex value and obviously can't do that so I had to serialize it first.